# Can I JsDoc a return value for a Factory method properly?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, jsdoc, oop

I am looking for ways to build a system where I do not need to load all source files in order to play the application. My past project had over 200 .js files (I am not kidding!) and it was really slow to do a page reload to test features you develop.

I looked into Dojo and I see how they have built a dynamic loader. Basically you just load a single core component, then everything else will be loaded when needed.

I am thinking about implementing a factory method in my application that allows me to construct new instances of objects in JavaScript:

```
var user = MyApp.create('MyApp.model.User');
```

instead of:

```
var user = new MyApp.model.User();
```

The reasoning why I'd like to ditch the new keyword is because the former approach allows me to dynamically load the component in a lazy-loaded fashion if it does not exist already. The factory method can just look if the target object is defined, and if it is not, it would load it.

The *only problem* I am facing with that is the fact IDEs no longer understand `user` is type of `MyApp.model.User` which is certainly not a good thing.

Is there a way to solve this dilemma? Can I somehow JsDoc that factory method?

Answer (score 2):

If your factory method returns various types of objects, based on the argument, then you can't document the return value for the factory method itself (using `@returns`) in a way that IDEs can make sense of. At least I'm not aware of any way to do it.

But you can solve your problem, easily, by annotating the variable which holds the object, like this:

```
/**
 * @type {MyApp.model.User}
 */
var user = MyApp.create('MyApp.model.User');
```

Of course, I don't know if your particular IDE can interpret this. Mine can (using Komodo).

Comment: I have been doing that for a long time. The problem is that you are repeating yourself and what I want to do is DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself). Instead of specifying that in 100's of places where I create an object, I want to specify it once in the factory method.

Comment: But, again, you can't document a specific return type - which is what an IDE would need - if your factory doesn't return that one specific type. So if you put it that way, it simply can't be done. You'd need a separate factory for every type of object, which presumably isn't what you want.

Comment: it certainly can be done, but not with the current version of JsDoc. There could be a way to document a factory. That would mean that the IDE reads the string you pass to the factory, and assumes the returned object is that.

Comment: Yes this is much needed, but seems so obvious a need that I'm surprised this doesn't exist already.  Has there been any update?